# word_delimiter on blocks of text

Tags: elasticsearch

It seems the `word_delimiter` is designed to only work on single terms. What if I had a block of text like the one below:

```
 "Contra-indications of paracetamol can be of certain sorts"
```

In this instance the `word_delimiter` takes the whole sentence and concatenates it, whereas I need it to only concatenate `"Contra-indications"` so that I may search for `contra indications`, `contra-indications` and `contraindications` but within a block of text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an analyzer like this one:

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "delimiter_filter": {
          "type": "word_delimiter",
          "catenate_words": true,
          "preserve_original": true
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "delimiter_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "whitespace",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "delimiter_filter"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "assets": {
      "properties": {
        "domain": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "delimiter_analyzer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And for your sample text - `Contra-indications of paracetamol can be of certain sorts` - these are the terms it's generating:

```
           "domain": [
              "be",
              "can",
              "certain",
              "contra",
              "contra-indications",
              "contraindications",
              "indications",
              "of",
              "paracetamol",
              "sorts"
           ]
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was after thank you! Last night I had the idea of using the whitespace tokenizer!